# Python: cracking the gc enigma

Tags: python, garbage-collection, python-2.6

I am trying to understand gc because I have got a large list in a program which I need to delete to free up some badly needed memory. The basic question I want to answer is `how can I find what is being tracked by gc and what has been freed?` following is code illustrating my problem

```
import gc
old=gc.get_objects()
a=1
new=gc.get_objects()
b=[e for e in new if e not in old]
print "Problem 1: len(new)-len(old)>1 :", len(new), len(old)
print "Problem 2: none of the element in b contain a or id(a): ", a in b, id(a) in b
print "Problem 3: The reference counts are insanely high, WHY?? "
```

IMHO this is weird behavior that isnt addressed in the [docs](http://docs.python.org/2.6/library/gc.html). For starters why does assigning a single variable create multiple entries for the gc? and why is none of them the variable I made??  Where is the entry for the variable I created in get_objects()?

EDIT: In response to martjin's first reponse I checked the following

```
a="foo"
print a in gc.get_objects()
```

Still no-go :( how can I check that a is being tracked by gc?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The result of `gc.get_objects()` is itself not tracked; it would create a circular reference otherwise:

```
>>> import gc
>>> print gc.get_objects.__doc__
get_objects() -> [...]

Return a list of objects tracked by the collector (excluding the list
returned).
```

You do not see `a` listed because that references one of the low-integer singletons. Python re-uses the same set of `int` objects for values between -5 and 256. As such, `a = 1` does not create a new object to be tracked. Nor will you see any other primitive types.

CPython garbage collection only needs to track container types, types that can reference *other* value because the only thing that GC needs to do is break circular references.

Note that by the time any Python script starts, already some automatic code has been run. `site.py` sets up your Python path for example, which involves lists, mappings, etc. Then there are the memoized `int` values mentioned above, CPython also caches `tuple()` objects for re-use, etc. As a result, on start-up, easily 5k+ objects are already alive before one line of your code has started.

Comment: @Martjin: thanks for your response, I have added one more example to clarify that the problem still occurs

Comment: @pushpen: small strings are interned as well. Use a custom class and instance: `class Foo: pass` then `foo = Foo()` and `foo in gc.get_objects()`.

Comment: @MartijnPieters That would explain if `gc.get_objects()` doesn't *grow* when a string is introduced later. But the string isn't in the list at all, and the list doesn't change if a string literal is introduced *after* getting the first object list (e.g. using the REPL). This is because the cycle GC has an optimization to not track object that can't be part of a cycle (including ints, floats, strings, and sometimes even lists of such types). There's never a `str` in `gc.get_objects()`, though of course it may contain objects that themselves refer to strings.

Comment: @delnan: I was coming to the same conclusion; just found confirmation, and recalled *why* it does it too.

Comment: By the way, your reasoning for why `a` is not present has the same flaw: If integers could occur, caching should only affect whether an integer occurs multiple times, not whether it occurs at all. The same resolution applies.

Comment: @delnan: I am trying to understand your argument but it seems that there is some subtlety of implementation that I am not getting, martjin initially wrote that `a=1` doesn't create new objects to be tracked isnt that what you are saying also?

Comment: @pushpen I agree that `a = 1` (or even just `1;`) does not create new objects. I am merely saying that this isn't the reason `a in gc.get_objects()` is false: It returns false because the `1` object is not tracked by the GC at all, regardless of whether it is cached.